# netstat command (net-tools) not generating expected response

Tags: apache, centos7, port80

I have installed netstat tool on Cent OS 7 to check the services running on specific port(s). To begin with, I want to check the service being run on port 80 (for ofcourse httpd) and I used the following command-

```
netstat -pnltu | grep -i "80"
```

The result that I got was not what I expected. I see values for port and PID that 'includes' 80 but nothing for Port 80 per se.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      1780/mysqld         
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      14608/java
```

PS - Port 80 for httpd has got issues that I was trying to understand and hence the need to run netstat command.

Comment: Are you actually able to connect to a service on port 80? If the answer to the previous question is "yes", what does your `iptables` NAT table look like (`iptables -t nat -S`)?

Comment: @larsks, many thanks for your comment. In the meantime, after posting the question, I had refreshed/reinstalled httpd and it is working now - as expected.